# Speed issue on using Linux subsystem search on a Windows server

Tags: linux, windows, performance, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm performing a search on a Windows server, who has a mapping to my Z:-drive (`\\<servername>\<base_directory>`). In there I would like to search inside a subdirectory, so we get `Z:\<subdirectory>`.

Next to that, I've installed a Linux subsystem on my Windows computer and I've created a mounting point, referring to the server (`/mnt/z`).

I'm launching a search inside that server's subdirectory in two ways:

- Via Notepad++, search for "keyword" inside the server's subdirectory.
- Via my Linux subsystem: `<Prompt inside /mnt/z/<subdirectory>> find ./ -name "*.p" -exec grep "keyword" {} /dev/null \;`

Both are working and give correct results, but I'm having an issue with the speed: Notepad++ works at a reasonable speed, but my Linux subsystem takes easily 10 times the amount of time for performing the same task.

Is that a known issue for Linux subsystems on Windows servers or is that an issue that I can handle in some way and in that case, how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

File I/O seems particularly slow in WSL, presumably because of the emulation into Windows filesystem calls. This is always improving, but just slow at the moment.

I sometimes also wonder, if caching doesn't work as well as it should. I don't have a great reference on this, but Phoronix has been doing benchmarks: [Look here](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=windows10-okt-wsl&num=2).

A lot of the benchmarks are OK really, but I/O bound things like sqlite or compiling stuff is like 20x worse in WSL (on local and SMB drives).

Quote: "significantly more work is needed by Microsoft to get the WSL I/O performance even remotely close to the Linux storage performance".